# Laravel 5: How do i use forms in my 'Views'

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im am a beginner in Laravel, running **version 5.2.16**. I have been using PHP for quite some time but i have to get used to the MVC structure.

I have successfully added the optional dependancy for Html and Form, and they work.

I am trying to add a view where a client can register to my site, this view includes various forms. Now, when i try to route the view (register.blade.php) to the controller (RegisterController.php) I keep getting errors.
I suspect that I use the namespaces wrong, or that i doesn't "Use" the right things.

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegister');
```

**RegisterController.php:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class RegisterController extends Controller {

    public function showRegister()
    {
        return view('register');
    }
}
```

In my **config/app.php** file i have added: (Should this be Illuminate instead of Collective?)

```
'providers' => [
...
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

'aliases' => [
...
'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

After i have made these changes i run:

```
$ composer update
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ php artisan route:clear
```

However, this still gives med the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Form' not found (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myProject/resources/views/register.blade.php)
```

Any ideas?

[My files are setup as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiCQu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Laravel versions < 5.0 `FormFacade` is already within your `app/config/app.php` but in Laravel versions > 5 you need to manually place the third party `Facades` like as

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's `composer.json` file to require `laravelcollective/html`.

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
}
```

Next, update Composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of `config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add `two class aliases` to the `aliases array` of `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
      'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
    // ...
  ],
```

[**Docs**](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have added something to my post.